# how do I change my default display gui with Qt gui at time of booting on linux

Tags: gui, bootloader, qt5

I have already made Qt GUI application, I want to run that application at the time of Linux booting. In simple meaning when I power on my Ubuntu I don't want that default desktop I want my Qt application as a display.